# In simple layman's terms what does getBean do in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Consider a line of code like this

```
AutomobileDriver ad=(AutomobileDriver)appContext.getBean("increaseSpeed");
```

Assume there is an `IncreaseSpeed` class which inherits from `AutomobileDriver` class

What does `getBean` do? What is the main function of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "simple layman's terms":

1. This assumes that Spring was told to create an object instance (possibly in an XML config file) that is identified (by Spring) as with the id "increaseSpeed" and has a class or parent class of `AutomobileDriver`.
2. You are asking the Spring context for a reference to (a) by default, the previously created object (this is called a singleton) or (b) a new instance of that object (prototype).

Answer (score 2):

In Spring, you can define a bean and give it an id.  Usually, Spring would prefer that you use *dependency injection* to access the bean.  However, Spring provides `getBean` as another way to access a bean by its id.

Basically, your code will return an instance of the bean with id "increaseSpeed".

Comment: This is still inversion of control, because the implementation is decided elsewhere. It's more manual labor, but conceptually the same.

Comment: @DaveNewton not quite, because the application is aware of the IOC container. In a classic IOC scenario, beans don't know where the dependencies come from.

Answer (score 2):

This code is requesting the bean named `increaseSpeed` from the Spring Application Context. Think of the application context as the pool of available objects, which has been configured from your Spring configuration XML. When the application context is started, it creates the beans in the configuration. This call simply asks for the one which is already there. The application context returns this "bean" as a `java.lang.Object` so you have to cast it to the appropriate type.

You might see this call as an entry point in a Spring application. This call is needed to get the first object out from the application context - from there, this object may have links to other objects which have been *injected* by Spring.

Answer (score 1):

A bean is a component that provides some functionality, the name of the bean indicates that it would be increase speed.

Those components are registered in a context called 'application context' and can be looked up by name. So if you want to increase the speed look at your apps-context for something that could do this.

More tecnical:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/